# I didn't make this edit - who did and why does the revision log say I did?

Tags: support, edits

I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855597/how-to-apply-css-in-jquery-error-placement)'s tags from [php](/questions/tagged/php) to [css](/questions/tagged/css) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but according to [the revision log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16855597/revisions), I changed 30 characters of code too... but I didn't. I only edited the tags (using the full inline post editor).

Who made this edit and why does the revision log say I edited the code?

The OP has reverted the changes to the code.

Comment: You must have been working on an initial post that was then ninja-edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this <s>is</s> could be the case:

- First OP asked the question where code was like this:

  ```
  pricehosting_price_native:{
                      required: true, 
                      number: true
                      }
  ```
- After you pressed the edit button, OP changed the code from `pricehosting_price_native` to `price`(**within the grace period**). But in your edit inline page the old one was present.
- When you pressed the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button, the new one (`price`) was replaced by `pricehosting_price_native`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The revision log is very misleading in that case though!

Comment: @KooKiz - When OP edited (during grace period), Danny Beckett didn't edited yet.